# "Show as Saved Image" in Content add-in

Tags: ms-office, office-addins

I have multiple Content apps (Office Add-ins) in a PowerPoint presentation. The apps need to be converted to image before distributing the presentation to the wider audience group. I know the way to do this is by clicking 'Show as Saved Image' menu in the context menu of the app. But with multiple apps in the document, this is a very tedious process as this will have to be done repeatedly and manually on each Content app. Is there a solution to implement 'show as saved image' on all Content apps in the document in a single step / click?

Desperately looking for a solution! Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

1. Save the file
2. File > Inspect Presentation/Check for Issues > Inspect Document
3. Deselect everything except "Content Add-ins"
4. Inspect
5. Replace All

Now all the content add-ins are replaced by their images permanently.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much Michael. This worked well. I really hope this solution will be acceptable to my users!

Comment: That is the office user way. But is there a way to do this via the content app?

Comment: @ndee: no, there is not